# Is there a Java equivalent for XmlDocument.LoadXml() from .NET?

Tags: c#, java, .net, xml, xmldocument

In `.NET` C#, when trying to load a `string` into `xml`, you need to use `XmlDocument` type from `System.Xml` and do the following:

**e.g:**

```
string xmlStr = "<name>Oscar</name>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
Console.Write(doc.OuterXml);
```

This seems simple but how can I do this in `Java`? Is it possible to load a `string` into `xml` using something directly, short and simple like above and avoid implementing other methods for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the constraint to "avoid using libraries" is a bit specious; that a "library" (such as `System.Xml`) in Java might not be there "by default" is not a useful rubric.  Java has a [bounty of XML parsing libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_XML) -- choose one; all of them, with a bit of effort, can be surfaced (either arleady there or via a minimal amount of API wrapping) in such a way to allow code samples such as yours to work.

Comment: but my point was that *whatever* XML API you choose, implementing such an API such that your sample code would work like that is very trivial.  Why not just choose an API and create a 4 or 5 line wrapper method that provides you with an interface such as you want?

Comment: Well, I just want something simple and short, the less code written, then is better, so it will "replicate" the .NET way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuildFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder doccumentBuilder = documentBuildFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = 
 doccumentBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<name>Oscar</name>".getBytes()));
```

You can traverse `Oscar` by:

```
String nodeText = document.getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent() ;         
System.out.println(nodeText);
```

To transaform back:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory =  TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
//to print the string in sysout, System.out
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult );
```

To get the result in String:

```
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outStream);
transformer.transform(source, result);
String resultString = new String( outStream.toByteArray());
System.out.println(resultString);
```

Comment: Nice :-) I got one question, how can I convert `Document document` to `string`?

Comment: @OscarJara Updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 3):

You have a choice of tree models in Java - DOM, XOM, JDOM, DOM4J. Many people (including Singh above) use DOM by default because it is included in the JDK, but it's probably the worst of the bunch, largely because it's the oldest (it was invented before namespaces came along), and because it tries to do too much (HTML, event handling etc, as well as XML). I'd suggest using JDOM2. It shouldn't be hard if you look at the Javadoc for you to find the method that builds a JDOM2 document from an input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a ton of libraries for working with XML. In addition to the many classes that work with XML included with the standard Java installation, there are lots of other open source libraries available. Here are a few options. Take a look at the docs and see which one meets your needs:

The [XStream Library](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) is very fast and easy to use. I've used it for XML serialization and I'm very happy with it.  If you would rather not use an extrenal library, then try 
the [javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) class that is demonstrated [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a String `str` to `Document` in Java, you can do following:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return docBuilder.parse(is);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this works, but I got one question, how can I make the `docBuilder.parse(is)` to `string` and print the `xml`

Comment: If you want to print the XML, probably u only want to do  System.out.println(str); create Document, to perform document manipulation over the XML document

Comment: Well, that's not the point, let me explain you briefly my problem itself: In .NET I got a xml string that is loaded from a static xml  resource file which I don't have access. Then some strings from this template gets replaced according to user selections but some nodes have to be removed if user selects one specific option. So, when this happens, the template (xml string) becomes with blank lines but thats not a problem cause when loading this into XmlDocument, everything gets well formed. The problem is that this logic will be used for Java too and don't happen the same as .NET